# CSS javascript/jquery variable use tutorials

Tags: javascript, variables, html

I'm trying to build a page which will display an image in a div and depending on what image it is this will populate 3 other separate divs with a mix of image and text content on the same page.

I just don't know where to start as all the variable tutorials/help I find either confuses the hell out of me or don't really apply to this particular situation.

So looking at it there is one large div (divA) and below that on the page there is another large div (divB) which contains three separate divs (divX, divY & divZ). I want the content of div's X,Y & Z to change depending on what is in div A. So if A has a variable of '1' then X,Y & Z will hold their own different pre designed '1' content. A'2' then X,Y & Z will hold their own '2' content....etc.

I will continue searching online but I thought someone could point me in the right direction or give me the run down on how to accomplish it.

Comment: How is the initial image selected, divA? Does a user select from a list of images or is this fed out upon some other preselected-predetermined content?

Comment: I'm hoping to have a gallery of images and when the user selects one it will display the page I described with that selected image filling divA. Then I will have what is essentially a next/previous button which will change the main window image variable causing the other divs to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code is filling the divs depending on the value of "mainWindow" using template as look up.

```
<div id="mainWindow">windowA</div>

<div>
    <div id="smallWindowA"></div>
    <div id="smallWindowB"></div>
    <div id="smallWindowC"></div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
var template = {
    "windowA" : [ "contentAA", "contentAB", "contentAC" ]
};

function setContent() {

    var content = document.getElementById("mainWindow").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("smallWindowA").innerHTML = template[content][0];
    document.getElementById("smallWindowB").innerHTML = template[content][1];
    document.getElementById("smallWindowC").innerHTML = template[content][2];

}

setContent();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering @Amberlamps. The script works well. However, I've been trying to insert an image into the "mainWindow" div, which although  displays fine, the javascript has a hard time identifying the <img> tag, which means the subsequent div contents ("smallWindowA", "smallWindowB" & "smallWindowC") aren't being set. I hope that makes sense. I guess what I'm asking is if the div "mainWindow" contains an image tag can the javascript still pick up on its innerHTML?

Comment: @RB101: Replace "windowA" in the `template` variable with the src of the image file, e.g. `"images/picture.jpg" : [ "contentAA", "contentAB", "contentAC" ]`. Then replace the definition of `content` with `document.getElementById("mainWindow").getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src`. That should do it.

Comment: I've tried fixing it up and it's only displaying that first main image. I'm pretty stumped as I don't think I've missed anything there. I uploaded the basic code above to [testPage](http://noodlepixel.com/site/tester.html).

Comment: @RB101: My mistake. `.src` get you the absolute path not the relative one. So you either replace your identifier in the `template` variable with the absolute path to the image or you add for example a `name` attribute to the Html like `<img src="icon.png" name="pictureA">`. Use `pictureA` as identifier in the `template` variable and use `.name` instead of `.src` in the JavaScript.

Comment: Excellent! Works a treat. Thanks for all the support, it's been a real help.